# How can I convert a json string to bson in the MongoDB console?

Tags: mongodb

Every example I see uses some kind of driver (how to do it in C#/java/etc.) There's the tojson function but there isn't a tobson one.

How can I convert a json string to bson object in the MongoDB console?

Comment: Why would you want to convert JSON to a binary format in the shell?

Comment: I'm trying to do a bulk insert and it fails for json strings. I suspect it will work if I use an array of bson objects. Another application is to create a copy of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to turn it into JSON so that you can insert it, not BSON.

This question has the answer as to how: [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)